# Parse sqlite query line by line

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite

i have a problem which i cant figure out myself, i have a SQLite database which contains data
to retrieve the data i use a bash script and the command `sqlite3 db "SELECT prkey FROM printers"`

the output is something like this:

1

3

4

5

6

7

i need to parse each line and use it for my next command. and with out the use of a `> file`

regards Marco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` loops work, but they are not very robust: they break if a line in the output has a space, and the shell must store the whole output of the query in memory before it starts running the loop. These two issues are easily dealt with:

```
sqlite3 db "SELECT ..." | while read prkey; do
   echo "do stuff with $prkey"
done
```

Comment: +1, indeed blank spaces would screw up the use of for, therefore this one is the more correct answer compared to the others. Hope others will acknowledge that, too.

Comment: You probably want to set:
```IFS='|'```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(sqlite3 db "SELECT prkey FROM printers"); do
  echo "line is --> $line" # do stuff with $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop on the return value of the sqlite command.

```
for prkey in `sqlite3 db "SELECT prkey FROM printers"`; do
    echo $prkey; #replace with your command
done;
```

Comment: Better to use `$()` over backticks. The latter is deprecated

Comment: @SiegeX: can you suggest a book/link to support your assertion?!

Comment: @STATUS: Sure, see [HERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03). Since both versions of the syntax are POSIX, and the `$()` can do everything the `\`\`` version can do but is much more easily nestable, the latter is, by definition, deprecated.